# Animação de link Css

Tags: html5, css3, css-hover

Ocorre a animação quando passo o mouse, mas quando removo ele volta sem animação.
Sabem me informar como ter o mesmo efeito de animação ao remover o mouse?

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  border-left: 4px;
}

.link:hover {
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-left: 4px solid blueviolet;
  color: blueviolet;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<!-- LINK ANIMADO -->
<a href="#" class="link">Saiba mais ></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá, vou dividir a resposta em duas partes

**Primeiro:**

A transition pode receber uma propriedade como **parametro**, como por exemplo a propriedade color

```
{
  transition: color .4s;
}
```

Se ela não receber nenhum parametro, ela usara todas as propriedades como parametro

**Segundo:**

Um elemento vai sempre receber as propriedades da sua classe, como por exemplo

```
.minha-classe{
  color: red
}
```

Esse elemento sempre vai ser vermelho, certo ? e agora se adicionarmos uma pseudo classe :hover

```
.minha-classe:hover{
  color: blue
}
```

Agora quando eu passar o meu cursor sob o elemento ele vai ser azul, ao retirar ele voltara a ser vermelho, a mesma coisa se aplica a propriedade **transition**, a animação só ira ser ativada quando você passar o cursor e nunca será chamada ao se retirar ele.

Voltando para o seu css, ele teria que ficar assim:

```
    <!-- CSS -->
<style>

    .link{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: cornflowerblue;
        border-left: 4px;
        transition: .4s;
    }
    .link:hover{
        padding-left: 30px;
        border-left: 4px solid blueviolet;
        color: blueviolet;
    }

</style>
```